# Python 2.7 - xlrd - Matching A String To a Cell Value

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, unicode, xlrd

Using Python 2.7 on Mac OSX Lion with `xlrd`

My problem is relatively simple and straightforward.  I'm trying to match a string to an excel cell value, in order to insure that other data, within the row that value will be matched to, is the correct value.

So, say for instance that `player = 'Andrea Bargnani'` and I want to match a row that looks like this:

```
 Draft      Player                        Team
 1      Andrea Bargnani -   Toronto Raptors
```

I do:

```
 num_rows = draftSheet.nrows - 1
 cur_row = -1
 while cur_row < num_rows:
     cur_row += 1
     row = draftSheet.row(cur_row)
     if row[1] == player:
           ranking == row[0]
```

The problem is that the value of `row[1]` is `text:u'Andrea Bargnani`, as opposed to just `Andrea Bargnani`.

I know that Excel, after Excel 97, is all unicode.  But even if I do `player = u'Andrea Bargnani'` there is still the preceding `text:`.  So I tried `player = 'text:'u'Andrea Bargnani'`, but when the variable is called it ends up looking like `u'text: Andrea Bargnani` and still does not produce a match.

I would like to then just strip the `test: u'` off of the returned `row[1]` value in order to get an appropriate match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get a `value` from the cell.

I've created a sample excel file with a text "Andrea Bargnani" in the A1 cell. And here the code explaining the difference between printing the `cell` and it's `value`:

```
import xlrd


book = xlrd.open_workbook("input.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

print sheet.cell(0, 0)  # prints text:u'Andrea Bargnani'
print sheet.cell(0, 0).value  # prints Andrea Bargnani
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I do `row[1].value` and get `u'Andrea Bargnani`.  I have written a function to deal with `u'`, though, so I'm good there!  Thanks again!